# android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout class not found

Tags: java, android

After importing android native ads templates module from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-native-templates

I cannot run the app because of the following error

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you mentioned uses support libraries. Lately all of support packages have been moved to androidx, you can check if your project uses androidx artifacts by checking your build.gradle, there the dependencies should be something like:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

Androidx and support libraries are not compatible, so if you want to use the library you have 3 choices:

1. Downgrade you application to use support libraries (**not recommended**)
2. Fork the repository and change imports. This is an easy job, you just need to replace all packages from support to androidx.
3. Import the source code to the android studio and use the option: Refactor |> Migrate to AndroidX (Not sure if it works with modules)

Comment: Yes i'm using androidx, please how do i do number 2?

Comment: I've managed to migrate the imports to androidx but still getting the error

Comment: Actually looks like there is someone who forked and upgraded to androidX https://github.com/rana01645/googleads-mobile-android-native-templates If you plan to use it in production please take a look at all modifications applied and pull this current version locally to your project.

Comment: Ok I forked the library and modified it myself, it builds without problems https://github.com/D4no0/googleads-mobile-android-native-templates . Clone/Download the repository then in android studio File|>New|>Import Module after that go to File|> Project Structure and add module as dependency to your app module.

Comment: Thanks, i've managed to get it working. Now i'v a problem using  guidelines.    `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.Guideline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

Comment: As I said before, all support libraries were moved to androidx, use the guideline located in androidx package. Also don't forget to mark this as the right answer since other are misleading and when somebody else will check this question, he will have more problems than solutions.

Answer (score 0):

did you notice that the `gnt_medium_template_view.xml` does not hava a layout?

All the code has to be inside of a `Layout` **like this**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView
      android:layout_height="350dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/native_ad_view"
      android:background="@drawable/gnt_outline_shape"
      >
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:id="@+id/background"
          >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView
            android:id="@+id/media_view"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/middle"
            />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_default_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/media_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/body"
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        >
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

          android:layout_width="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/gnt_default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/content"
            />
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/gnt_default_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/headline"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
              android:layout_weight="0.5"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/row_two"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/primary"
                android:background="@color/gnt_white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_text_size_large"
                android:textColor="@color/gnt_gray"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                ></TextView>
          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/row_two"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
              android:layout_weight="0.5"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headline"
              >
            <TextView
                android:background="@drawable/gnt_rounded_corners_shape"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/gnt_ad_indicator_width"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ad_notification_view"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/gnt_ad_indicator_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_ad_indicator_top_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/gnt_default_margin"
                android:text="Ad"
                android:textColor="@color/gnt_ad_green"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_ad_indicator_text_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                >
            </TextView>
            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                android:background="@color/gnt_white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_text_size_small"
                android:textColor="@color/gnt_gray"
                android:numStars="0"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ad_notification_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </RatingBar>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secondary"
                android:background="@color/gnt_white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_text_size_small"
                android:textColor="@color/gnt_gray"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ad_notification_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                ></TextView>

          </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/gnt_no_size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/gnt_default_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gnt_default_margin"
            android:id="@+id/body"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cta"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/middle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gnt_default_margin"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/gnt_blue"
            android:textColor="@color/gnt_white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/body"
            />

      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

if you can notice i change `merge` to `ConstraintLayout`, you can use others too as: `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`. **Of course** each one has a different **purpose**.

I guess it might be the problem, if it is... you need to fix the `gnt_small_template_view.xml` too. **Hope it helps**.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency for constraint-layout in `gradile`. See Code

`dependencies {
//Don't forget to add dependency of constraint-layout
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Comment these lines if you are getting error in ContentBinding File

```
        buildFeatures {
           dataBinding true
           viewBinding true
       }
```