# ANDROID STUDIO builds succesfully but doesn't run

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, cs50

I've just built my first android app copying the code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTy13ioTddg&t=594s

The app builds without problems but when I try to run it, it suddenly closes.

[image: That's what happen]

That's the message of the debugger:

```
12/02 12:19:56: Launching 'app' on Pixel_3a_API_30_x86.
Install successfully finished in 519 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.pokedex/com.example.pokedex.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.pokedex | com.example.pokedex.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.pokedex | com.example.pokedex.test
Connecting to com.example.pokedex
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.pokedex is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:52033', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10153(com.example.pokedex) identical 2 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1475)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/example.pokede: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/example.pokede: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pokedex, PID: 8349
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pokedex/com.example.pokedex.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.pokedex:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.pokedex:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.pokedex:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.pokedex:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.pokedex:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.pokedex.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~ikbXqJo2xtaJUvZzC7gM8Q==/com.example.pokedex-kRHbfAkGOaaI21CGLAjxuQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~ikbXqJo2xtaJUvZzC7gM8Q==/com.example.pokedex-kRHbfAkGOaaI21CGLAjxuQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 26 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8349 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:52033', transport: 'socket'
```

This is my Main Activity:

```
package com.example.pokedex;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter=new PokedexAdapter();
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }
}
```

Activity main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pokedex_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pokedex_row">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pokedex_row_text_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Android Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pokedex">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Pokedex">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've been trying to solve this problem several days so I would be very thankful if someone can help me!

Comment: You have some issue related MainActivity and xml inflating. Will be helpfully if you paste onCreate from that activity.

Comment: It seems like you run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627902/android-support-constraint-constraintlayout-class-not-found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried you changing your ConstraintLayout to use androidx instead of support

try changing the opening tag of activity_main.xml to be:

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

and corresponding closing tag to be

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

and then sync your project while connected to the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. I've spent a lot of days with that, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has problem with ConstraintLayout, can you share your xml files, that way I can help you batter.

Answer (score 0):

I experience this error from time to time and use to solve by doing the following:

- First, check if you have `ConstraintLayout` implementation in your `app` `Gradle` config
- Then  make sure there is no Error(maybe a semantic one) in your layout `XML file`

If the error persists, consider adding those two files to your question description so that one can easily help

Good Luck!